# How to give fixed height to a sliverList in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to make a collapsible toolbar that shrinks when scrolling the page.

For that, I am using Slivers. By using `SliverList`, when the data gets scrolled, it goes up in the phone screen top battery and time transparent bar. Hence, I want to give the list fixed height so that it gets scrolled in a limited area.

[image]

I tried putting the `SliverList` into a `SingleChildScrollView`, a `SizedBox`, or a `Container`. But none worked.

```
SliverList(
  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Text("Text"),
    );
  },
  chikdCount:100,
),
```

Comment: Should you use `SafeArea` or `SliverSafeArea`?

Comment: Exactly something like that so that I can avoid scrolling onto the os header.

Comment: But couldn't find how to use sliversafearea inside the sliverlist?

Comment: Can you post your code with the `SafeArea`?

Answer (score -3):

You can change the height of slivers by using `itemExtend` property in `SliverFixedExtentList`. Henceforth all the children will take the same height as 150.0. Can you check the below code?

```
SafeArea(
   child: CustomScrollView(
    slivers: <Widget>[
      SliverAppBar(
        title: Text('SliverAppBar'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        expandedHeight: 200.0,
        flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
          background: Image.asset('assets/forest.jpg', fit: BoxFit.cover),
        ),
      ),
      SliverFixedExtentList(
        itemExtent: 150.0,
        delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
          [
            Container(color: Colors.red),
            Container(color: Colors.purple),
            Container(color: Colors.green),
            Container(color: Colors.orange),
            Container(color: Colors.yellow),
            Container(color: Colors.pink),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
));
```

Comment: It is still giving the same result. I want to stop the content below os header so that the items are not getting scrolled into the top status bar of the mobile screen.

Comment: The above code increased the padding between the children which I am already getting by any of sizedbox or putting into container or using above method.

Comment: But how do I stop the content from occupying the status bar area.

Comment: SafeArea, perhaps?

Comment: You can use `SafeArea` widget to the parent of all the widgets in the build method to restrict the content that occupying in the status bar.